# wpf app msi created by wix not working due to dependency issue?

Tags: wpf, wix, windows-installer

[Here is my solution.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3UsSWWqWKe2WVdWak1EWVNZamc/view?usp=sharing)
I have a basic wpf application which uses cefsharp to show google.com. The app works fine when run from my bin folder in VisualStudio itself.

For this application I have created the following WiX file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"><?define WpfApplication6_TargetDir=$(var.WpfApplication6.TargetDir)?>
<Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="acv" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject1" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject1" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
        <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
            <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
        <!-- </Component> -->
        <Component Id="WpfApplication6.exe" Guid="*">
          <File Id="WpfApplication6.exe" Name="WpfApplication6.exe" Source="$(var.WpfApplication6_TargetDir)WpfApplication6.exe" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="WpfApplication6.exe.config" Guid="*">
          <File Id="WpfApplication6.exe.config" Name="WpfApplication6.exe.config" Source="$(var.WpfApplication6_TargetDir)WpfApplication6.exe.config" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="CefSharp.WinForms.dll" Guid="*">
          <File Id="CefSharp.WinForms.dll" Name="CefSharp.WinForms.dll" Source="$(var.WpfApplication6_TargetDir)CefSharp.WinForms.dll" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="CefSharp.dll" Guid="*">
          <File Id="CefSharp.dll" Name="CefSharp.dll" Source="$(var.WpfApplication6_TargetDir)CefSharp.dll" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="CefSharp.Core.dll" Guid="*">
          <File Id="CefSharp.Core.dll" Name="CefSharp.Core.dll" Source="$(var.WpfApplication6_TargetDir)CefSharp.Core.dll" />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

This code creates the setup, and when the application runs after installing the following exception occurs: Could not find cefsharp.core or one of its dependencies is not loaded.

This error appears when Visual c++ is not present.
How do I fix this, as I have Visual c++ installed.
Should I add any references in my WiX file?

Comment: What isn't being loaded if you try to open the cefsharp.core.dll in depends.exe on the installation test machine? Maybe you don't have the right version of c++ redistributables or cefsharp.core.dll needs a different version that you just happened to already have on your build machine?

Comment: Sounds like a missing runtime like Brian suggests.